# vue.js - how to update childs data on parent's data update without this.$parent[...]

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am taking my first steps with Vue.js and i like it very much however i met a small problem and i hope for help with solving this one.

Please check my fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/8410/

What i am trying to achieve is puting some buttons in relationship with others, for now, quite hardcoded, however if you click "settings on" button "setting1" and "setting2" button become visible. It works as intended but i want to root Vue instance to hold information when buttons are visible or not via this.settings = true (visible) or false (not visible). When button is created it is checked and button become visible or not depending on this.settings value. 
However because i use:

```
  template: '<div @click="kalregClicker" class="button" :class="{isNotVisible : !this.$parent[this.type]}"><slot></slot> {{ status}} {{ !this.$parent[this.type]}}</div>',
```

every change root's this.settings causes change of visibility of buttons and it is good. But somehow i guess that using everywhere this.$parent[this.type] is ugly. I'd prefer something like:

```
  template: '<div @click="kalregClicker" class="button" :class="{isNotVisible : !status}"><slot></slot> {{ status }} {{ !this.$parent[this.type]}}</div>',
```

or

```
  template: '<div @click="kalregClicker" class="button" :class="{isNotVisible : checkVisibility()}"><slot></slot> {{ status }} {{ !this.$parent[this.type]}}</div>',
```

and checkVisibilty would look like this:

```
function () {
   this.status = this.$parent[this.type];
   return this.status;
}
```

..but it doesnt work. 
The question is: how to make updating root's this.settings to true/false to impact 's component this.status so it changes look and behaviour of  component without using everywhere this.$parent[...] 
I hope i made myself clear :)
Kalreg.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Sending-Messages-to-Parents-with-Events

Comment: Also https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have `status` itself become a computed property.

Remove it from `data` declaration and do:

```
computed: {
 status() { return this.$parent[this.type] == undefined ? true : this.$parent[this.type]; }
}
```

You can use it like:

```
:class="{isNotVisible : !status}"
```

[**JSFiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/eywraw8t/8696/).